# Trigger to distribute custom amount from account to its correspondind contacts equally

Tags: apex, trigger

I am getting the following error in the below code :
"Unexpected token '<'. at line 25 column 9  "

```
trigger shareMoney on Contact (after insert , after update , after delete) {

    set<id> accountid = new set<id>();

    if(trigger.isAfter && (trigger.isInsert || trigger.isUpdate) ){

        for(Contact co : trigger.new){

            accountid.add(co.accountid);

        }
    }

    if(trigger.isDelete){


        for(Contact co : trigger.old){

             accountid.add(co.accountid);

        }

    }

    // The line below this is line 25
    List<Account> clist=[select id,IndividualMoney__c,(select id,total_number__c,Total_money__c, from Contacts) from Account where id in : accountid limit 1];

    list<Contact> money = new list<Contact>();
    for(Contact ac : clist){
        money.add(ac);
        ac.IndividualMoney__c = ac.Total_money__c/ac.total_number__c;

        upsert ac.IndividualMoney__c;

    }

}
```

---

Here are the corrections suggested by simon but still no result.

```
trigger shareMoney on Contact (after insert , after update , after delete) {

    set<id> accountid = new set<id>();

    if(trigger.isAfter && (trigger.isInsert || trigger.isUpdate) ){

        for(Contact co : trigger.new){

            accountid.add(co.accountid);

        }
    }

    if(trigger.isDelete){


        for(Contact co : trigger.old){

            accountid.add(co.accountid);

        }

    }

    List<Account> clist=[select id,total_number__c,Total_money__c,(select id,IndividualMoney__c from Contacts) from Account where id in : accountid limit 1];

    list<Account> money = new list<Account>();
    for(Account ac : clist){




        money.add(ac);
        ac.IndividualMoney__c = ac.Total_money__c/ac.total_number__c;

        upsert clist.IndividualMoney__c;

    }

}
```

Comment: damn it. sorry people, I edited the post to make it use the code formatter, but I have probably lost the line number correlation now!

Comment: I used the original code, with all of its extraneous newlines, and formatted it. That should mean the line number of the error should match the lines in the provided code (I also marked which line is line 25)

Comment: Sorry people the new edited code is:

Comment: You can **[edit]** your own posts. Please stop posting answers to update the code you have written. Just change it in your question.

Answer (score 3):

So I found multiple mistakes in the above code.

1. First to solve your error remove the comma after `Total_money__c` in
   `Account` `SOQL`
2. You have `clist` of type `Account` and in the `for loop` you are casting it to Contact

   `for(Contact ac : clist){`
3. You are upserting a field i.e. `upsert ac.IndividualMoney__c;`. You should either upsert a list or a sObject. In your case it might me `list<contact> money`
4. Any `DML` operation should be outside the for loop to avoid Salesforce governor limits

Try to correct these things and achieve the functionality.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure how this is even saving... because in your subquery you have broken field selectors:

```
(select id,total_number__c,Total_money__c, from Contacts)
```

You can't have the last comma after `Total_money__c` as far as a I know; so get rid of that; I think that will kick the compiler back into shape and it should stop complaining about the angle bracket... all of which look valid.

Also, you shouldn't have and upsert (`upsert ac.IndividualMoney__c;`) inside a loop at the bottom... even if it is (oddly) a loop over a query with a LIMIT 1...

Comment: Simon , Please help to ammend my code so that i can complete my task.
I am a newbie in salesforce

Comment: @user53852 Are you a newbie to coding? I would think that writing queries is a pretty basic thing. There's nothing wrong with being a newbie - there is, however, something wrong with asking someone to make the proper changes to your code just to complete a task. Try to learn WHY the problem happened. (Plus, they've told you where the problem is. Please change the code as Simon advised and see what happens.)

Comment: David can you suggest me some good sources to learn fast

Comment: Do you want to be a good developer, or do you want to learn a few things quickly? Any skill takes time to learn. If you haven't heard of Trailhead by now, then why are you working as a Salesforce developer?